# wild card matching in text string

Tags: regex, algorithm, wildcard, string-matching

My friend give this wild card(*) matching algorithm . Here is the code .

```
//This function compares text strings, one of which can have wildcards ('*').
//
BOOL GeneralTextCompare(
        char * pTameText,             // A string without wildcards
        char * pWildText,             // A (potentially) corresponding string with wildcards
        BOOL bCaseSensitive = FALSE,  // By default, match on 'X' vs 'x'
        char cAltTerminator = '\0'    // For function names, for example, you can stop at the first '('
)
{
        BOOL bMatch = TRUE;
        char * pAfterLastWild = NULL; // The location after the last '*', if we’ve encountered one
        char * pAfterLastTame = NULL; // The location in the tame string, from which we started after last wildcard
        char t, w;

        // Walk the text strings one character at a time.
        while (1)
        {
                t = *pTameText;
                w = *pWildText;

                // How do you match a unique text string?
                if (!t || t == cAltTerminator)
                {
                        // Easy: unique up on it!
                        if (!w || w == cAltTerminator)
                        {
                                break;                                   // "x" matches "x"
                        }
                        else if (w == '*')
                        {
                                pWildText++;
                                continue;                           // "x*" matches "x" or "xy"
                        }
                        else if (pAfterLastTame)
                        {
                                if (!(*pAfterLastTame) || *pAfterLastTame == cAltTerminator)
                                {
                                        bMatch = FALSE;
                                        break;
                                }
                                pTameText = pAfterLastTame++;
                                pWildText = pAfterLastWild;
                                continue;
                        }

                        bMatch = FALSE;
                        break;                                           // "x" doesn't match "xy"
                }
                else
                {
                        if (!bCaseSensitive)
                        {
                                // Lowercase the characters to be compared.
                                if (t >= 'A' && t <= 'Z')
                                {
                                        t += ('a' - 'A');
                                }

                                if (w >= 'A' && w <= 'Z')
                                {
                                        w += ('a' - 'A');
                                }
                        }

                        // How do you match a tame text string?
                        if (t != w)
                        {
                                // The tame way: unique up on it!
                                if (w == '*')
                                {
                                        pAfterLastWild = ++pWildText;
                                        pAfterLastTame = pTameText;
                                        w = *pWildText;

                                        if (!w || w == cAltTerminator)
                                        {
                                                break;                           // "*" matches "x"
                                        }
                                        continue;                           // "*y" matches "xy"
                                }
                                else if (pAfterLastWild)
                                {
                                        if (pAfterLastWild != pWildText)
                                        {
                                                pWildText = pAfterLastWild;
                                                w = *pWildText;

                                                if (!bCaseSensitive && w >= 'A' && w <= 'Z')
                                                {
                                                        w += ('a' - 'A');
                                                }

                                                if (t == w)
                                                {
                                                        pWildText++;
                                                }
                                        }
                                        pTameText++;
                                        continue;                           // "*sip*" matches "mississippi"
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                        bMatch = FALSE;
                                        break;                                   // "x" doesn't match "y"
                                }
                        }
                }

                pTameText++;
                pWildText++;
        }

        return bMatch;
}
```

This algo works as follow (according to me)

```
mississippi     *sip*
mississippi     sip*
ississippi      sip*
ssissippi       sip*
sissippi        ip*
sissippi        sip* pAfterLastWild is used to restore the location 
issippi         ip*
ssippi          p*
ssippi          sip* again pAfterLastWild is used here.
sippi           ip*
sippi           sip* here also.
ippi            ip*
ppi             p*
pi              *
i               *
```

I am not able to figure out why **pAfterLastTame** is needed and what does this piece of code is doing here as i am not able to find use of it .

```
else if (pAfterLastTame)
                        {
                                if (!(*pAfterLastTame) || *pAfterLastTame == cAltTerminator)
                                {
                                        bMatch = FALSE;
                                        break;
                                }
                                pTameText = pAfterLastTame++;
                                pWildText = pAfterLastWild;
                                continue;
                        }
```

This algo is pretty fast as number of comparisons are equal to size of tameString (correct me i am wrong) .
Does any one know more efficient algorithm than this ??

Comment: I like the use of 'tame' to distinguish from 'wild' when used with strings. But no - I would never roll my own. There are good algorithms to do this on every platform I use. Why do you ask?

Comment: I was not figuring out why that code is needed ..

Comment: Add a printf statement in the loop that you don't understand - so you can see when it is called and what it is doing. Seems to me it is entered when you are in a "tame" part of the string (ie 'vanilla' comparison, no wildcards).

Comment: Well, performance is okay when the string matches, but there are cetreinly degererate cases: try matching `"mississippi"` to `"m*x"`. That case also explains what `pAfterLastTame` is used for: It is used to backtrack to previous positions when `tame` has run out without a match.

Comment: @M Oehm - why to backtrack  to previous positions  when tame has run out without a match.I think that's not needed ????